# How to uptate a property in data() from within a callback function in beforeMount

Tags: vue.js

I am using opentypejs + vuejs.

How can I update the value of this.font from whithin the callback function in the beforeMount function?

thank you in advance for your help.

Tshitshi

My snippet :

```
data () {
  return {
    font: null
  }

beforeMount () {
      console.log('Maker component Before mounted.')
     var opentype = require('opentype.js')
     var fs = require('fs')
     var path = require('path')
     opentype.load('/fonts/FiraSansOT-Medium.otf', function (err, font) {
        if (err) {
          alert('Could not load font: ' + err)
        } else {
          // Use your font here.
          console.log("loaded the font",font)
          this.font = font
        }
      })
```